# marble mouse events not work on map qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am developing a map application using Marble. I use `QGraphicsProxyWidget` to wrap `MarbleWidget` and display it in Qml.
However, mouse events do not work on the map; I can't move, pan or zoom it but I can still use zoom and pan tools included in the right-bottom screen.

The same behaviour occurs when using the
qml example of `MarbleWidget`.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be quite beneficial if you could see your code

Comment: Thank for response.

My code is in the link below. Sorry, I dont know how to upload here so I use dropbox.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlgkdowa1io9tn3/MarbleQml.zip?dl=0

I am using qt4 on opensuse 13.1.

Comment: You can read more about marble here: https://github.com/shentok/marble

Comment: Hi,how you build and use QML examples? I use Qt 5.15 and I cant Run QML Example which provide [here](https://marble.kde.org/dev-intro.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Just implement two virtual functions in MyMapWidget:

```
void MyMapWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    return;
}

void MyMapWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    return;
}
```

It forwards mouseEvent to MarbleInputHandler and it worked